# Python Custom Function in Statsmodels formula

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using statsmodel to run linear regression.

My model looks like:

```
Y = beta1*x1^(beta2)*(beta3+x3)^beta4*x4^(beta5)
```

I know by using statsmodel, it has too be linear regression. So I need to do log transform,

then the equation becomes:

```py
y = logY = log(beta1) + beta2*log(x2) + beta4*log(beta3+x3) + beta5*log(x4)
```

Can I do this in statsmodel?

If I can, then how to customize this function?

Thank you!

Steve

Comment: The problematic term is beta3. Are you trying to estimate its value as well or do you know its value apriori?

Comment: no idea at all. that is the problem

Comment: So does that mean that you only know the values of x1, x2, x3 and x4?

Comment: yes, I do know the values of all x